# PowerBuilder Classic, Web Services, and Time Zones

Tags: powerbuilder

Does PowerBuilder Classic have any support for working with time zones, especially in regards to web service calls? I am looking for something like .NET's DateTimeOffset class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a native support, but you can work around with the system API:

- `GetTimeOfDayInfo()` (seems undocumented? from kernel32.dll)
- [`TIME_OF_DAY_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa370959(v=vs.85).aspx) struct from Lm.h
- [`NetRemoteTOD()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa370612(v=vs.85).aspx) (from netapi32.dll)
- `LocalhostTOD()` (also undocumented? from netapi32.dll)

There is an example on the Real's Howto : [Get the time and date from a server](http://www.rgagnon.com/pbdetails/pb-0250.html)